# How to show unread IMAP mail count in Byobu

Tags: mail, imap, byobu

Byobu supports `mail notification':

```
mail - system mail for the current user; the letter '[M]' is displayed
in the lower bar toward the left in black text on a grey background
```

How could system mail be set to regard IMAP accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your system mail client included in the mailutils package to receive mails from you online account (e.g. gmail). Last time I checked the mail notification feature in byobu was premature. See https://answers.launchpad.net/byobu/+question/143784

Comment: thanks, do u know if alpine can be used for that maybe?